# The word "relate" (a nuance)

Tags: word-usage

May I say: "The jackal relates to the dog as the tiger to the cat"? Or must it be "corresponds", or anything else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way this is typically expressed in English is simply by using the verb *is*:

> *The jackal is to the dog as the tiger is to the cat.*

Personally, I'd avoid using *relates*. When I read:

> *The jackal relates to the dog...*

I imagine the two animals conversing somehow (perhaps over a [card game](https://www.google.com/search?q=dogs+playing+poker&safe=off&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&biw=1616&bih=919) or something). It's not ungrammatical; it's just not usual.

Answer (score 3):

I've usually seen these type of statements styled as

*"A is to B as X is to Y"*

So in the case of your analogy, **"Jackal is to dog, as tiger is to cat"**

Comment: Have you dropped the articles intentionally?

Comment: Yes I did - analogies such as these are usually indefinite - we're not talking about a specific jackal or a specific tiger. Therefore the definite article the is not required. 

Of course if my assumption is incorrect, and you are actually referring to a specific jackal, dog, tiger and cat, then I'm wrong :)